# Installing the pg_trgm extension for PostgreSQL RDS instance

Tags: gitlab

Connecting to AWS RDS postgres instance to install pg_trgm as part of installing gitlab on aws. From where should I run the command sudo /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql -U gitlab -h  -d gitlabhq_production ?

I tried to use pgAdmin from my local machine using the AWS RDS postgres endpoint.

I expect the output of

psql (9.4.7)
Type "help" for help.

gitlab=# CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
gitlab=# \q

Answer (score 0):

This [guide shows](https://repository.prace-ri.eu/git/help/university/high-availability/aws/README.md):

> Connect to your new RDS instance to verify access and to install
>   a required extension.
>   We can find the host or endpoint by selecting the instance and  we just created and after the details drop down we'll find it labeled as 'Endpoint'; do remember not to include the colon and port
>   number.

```
sudo /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql -U gitlab -h <rds-endpoint> -d gitlabhq_production
psql (9.4.7)
Type "help" for help.
```

See "[Connecting to a DB Instance Running the MySQL Database Engine](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html)"

> To find the endpoint for a MySQL DB instance in the AWS Management Console:
>
> - Open the RDS console and then choose Databases to display a list of your DB instances.
> - Choose the MySQL DB instance name to display its details.
> - On the `Connectivity & security` tab, copy the endpoint.
>     Also, note the port number.
>     You need both the endpoint and the port number to connect to the DB instance.

[image: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/images/MySQLConnect1.png]

> If an endpoint value is `mysql–instance1.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com` and the port value is `3306`, then you would specify the following values in a MySQL connection string:
>
> - For host or host name, specify `mysql–instance1.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`
> - For port, specify `3306`

You should therefore be able to run this from anywhere on your machine.
Provided you did declare your [gitlabhq_production instance](https://repository.prace-ri.eu/git/help/university/high-availability/aws/README.md#rds) first:

[image: https://repository.prace-ri.eu/git/help/university/high-availability/aws/img/rds-net-opt.png]